# 1px "padding" in Safari/Opera/Chrome

Tags: css, safari, whitespace, opera, padding

I've been searching for information on this, and I see a lot of similar problems (percentage widths calculation problems, padding problems, floats in opposite directions, Safari+Chrome problems, etc), but nothing I've tried seems to fix this one.

I have a mystery 1px vertical space between my content area and my navbar for part of the page heightwise in Safari, Opera, and Chrome. It works fine on FFand IE with no space.

This is the page:
http://the-polyglot.net/uploads/problem_site/

I really apologize for the inefficient, redundant, unorganized messy stylesheet that I've yet to clean up--I just picked up this site again after it lying dormant several years and I was just about to go through and clean up before I discovered this problem.

The most relevant selectors are #right_navbar, #reg_content (the text area), and #main_content (the container). The space seems to coincide with the area governed by #main_content if you check Opera's inspector, but I don't know why. I can fix the issue in Opera/Safari/Chrome by applying `padding-left: 1px;` to #right_navbar... but then that breaks the entire layout in every other browser.

I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: The space is in Chrome too btw.

Comment: My bad--you're right.  I must have checked it on Chrome while I had the "fix" in the stylesheet and forgot it still wasn't correct. I'll edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `background-color` for the id `#main_content`

```
#main_content {
  min-height: 630px;
  /*background-color: #D1EBF8;*/
}
```